# C++ std::string search with special characters

Tags: c++, string, search

I got a long string from a HTML request. I need to find the following substring within:

```
<b><i>
```

However when I'm trying to search it gives me wrong results.

If I replace the string with something, not containing < or > it works flawlessly.

Relevant code:
(not copied, might have some typos, but works without special characters)

```
std::string readBuffer; //longlongstring
std::string starttag;
std::string endtag;

size_t sstart;
size_t send;

//...................

sstart=readBuffer.find(starttag);
send=redBuffer.find(endtag);

correction=readBuffer.substr(sstart,send-sstart);

//....................
```

So yeah, if anyone happens to know a way to fix this, I'd very much be greatful :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can make the search for the closing tag a little more effective by setting the `sstart` as the start position to search from: `send = readBuffer.find(endtag, sstart);`.

Comment: As for your question, it would help us to help us if you tell what the actual results are, and what you expected them to be. Please provide a complete example with actual and expected results.

Comment: Results are -1 and -1. Expected result be the word between the start and end tag. 

For example:
If I have this string:

...<b><i>Berlin</b></i>

starttag being <b><i>
and
endtag being </b></i>

I'd expect to get "Berlin" as a result. 

It works if I use strings without special charactrs instead

Comment: That is [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), which means the string you searched for was not found. Please provide a complete example, with you showing the values you search for and a sample input string you search for those values in. I recommend you read about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it will help us understand your problem better, and might even help you find the problem yourself.

Comment: Most likely your starttag, endtag, or buffer is not what you think it is.  Create a short, simple and compiling example of your problem.  Eliminate parts you do not think are important, and check to make sure the problem still occurs.  Ideally eliminate file io, use a constant string.  This may involve shortening said string.  It could be a file io problem, but this will let you know if it is.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I'm a idiot and was having a typo in the HTML request, thus not geting the expected response, the code was correct all along.

Sorry for wasting your time guys and thanks for helping me find the mistake..

Answer (score 3):

This works as expected:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string> 

int main(int,char**)
{
  std::string data = "...<b><i>Berlin</b></i>";
  size_t sstart = data.find("<b><i>")+6;
  size_t send = data.find("</b></i>");
  std::string correction = data.substr(sstart,send-sstart);
  assert(correction=="Berlin");
  return 0;
}
```

If you create a small complete example like this, but where you get a failure, then it would make it much easier to determine what the problem is.